# Why does CSS break in safari with multiple repeating-linear-gradients

Tags: css, ios, web, safari

I'm testing a webpage on chrome and safari iOS. When I use the CSS class below, the browser displays a pseudo-checkboard pattern [web page with pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RXjh.png). But the same style on iOS safari shows [web page with no pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuyOB.png). It seems to be a problem with using "repeating-linear-gradient" twice. Any advice?

```
#background {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: var(--ion-color-dark);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      var(--theme-primary-color) 25%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
      var(--theme-primary-color) 75%,
      var(--theme-primary-color)
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      var(--ion-toolbar-background) 25%,
      #ffffff 25%,
      #ffffff 75%,
      var(--ion-toolbar-background) 75%,
      var(--ion-toolbar-background)
    );
  background-position: 0 0, 40px 40px;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, it's an interaction with css variables and multiple repeating-linear-gradients. The solution is to not use multiple variables for the colour